# C++ return value storage in a stack frame

Tags: c++, stack, callstack, function-call

```cpp
int f(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

int main(){
    f(1,2);
}
```

In this example, when calling function `f`, there is not a specific variable storing the addition result of `a` and `b`. My question is: where will the result of `a+b` be stored?

Comment: In a typical ABI, `int` would be returned on a CPU register. For larger return types that won't fit on a register, in effect there's a hidden `void*` parameter to memory provided by the caller; the function places its return value into that memory. For details, consult your compiler's documentation - the exact mechanism is implementation-dependent.

Comment: The answer here varies depending on the compiler and operating system. The C++ standard imposes no specific requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will be moved to a temporary registers.
it will load the values, then call f(int,int)
take a look to the disassembly:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this, which tool do you use to display disassembly code?

Comment: You can use compiler explorer (godbolt), it’s free and it’s online